# Searching a few columns in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, web

I got a a Database with a few columns.
I want to add to my search the option to search not only one column like Project. I want to search a few more columns too.. so the search will look for Project or ServerName or IP and search all of the columns or a few of them.

I tried (Project__icontains=query, ServerName__icontains=query) but it said wrong syntax.

index.html:

```
def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()

        if query:
            posts = serverlist.objects.filter(Project__icontains=query)
        else:
            posts = serverlist.objects.all()
    #    else:
```

models.py:

```
  from django.db import models


class serverlist(models.Model):
    ServerName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    Owner = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Project = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    IP = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    ILO = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    Rack = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q)

from the docs:

> A Q object (django.db.models.Q) is an object used to encapsulate a collection of keyword arguments. These keyword arguments are specified as in “Field lookups” above.

an example:

```
posts = serverlist.objects.filter(
     Q(Project__icontains=query)|Q(ServerName__icontains=query)
)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Accept the answer if it was helpful please :)

Comment: Hi efkin, 
Do you have an email I can contact you?

Comment: Hi efkin, 
I have many more questions in my django. can you check them out and I will give you a tick?